# Combination of two bytes calculation

Tags: string

I'm trying to calculate the result from two bytes returned from a string.
I know that the expected value should = 250 and the two bytes have values of [3E, 80]

When working this out on a calculator do I use the 3E value and move it 8 bits to the left using the RoL function? If so how do I then use the result combined with the 80 value? Add the two values together?

Thanks.

Comment: The way you describe makes sense. However, `3E 80` would not represent the value `250`, but `16000`; please clarify.